# NFC permission required: Neither user 10711 nor current process has android.permission.NFC

Tags: javascript, android, nfc, android-permissions

I'm developing an android application with vue/capacitor/ionic where the user can scan NFC tags.

I'm receiving this error and cannot find anything to solve it:

> NFC permission required: Neither user 10711 nor current process has android.permission.NFC.

I have already added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />` to my AndroidManifest.xml. To my knowledge this should allow permission but it doesn't..?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Further code if necessary:

```
<script setup>
import 'normalize.css';
import router from '../router';

import { Nfc, NfcUtils, NfcTagTechType } from '@capawesome-team/capacitor-nfc';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';

const read = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    Nfc.addListener('nfcTagScanned', async (event) => {
      await Nfc.stopScanSession();
      resolve(event.nfcTag);
    });

    Nfc.startScanSession();
  });
};
</script>
```

Comment: On your android device, find your app in Settings->Apps. Check to see what permissions are enabled.

Comment: "No permissions allowed". I cannot change the permissions of the app(Atleast I cannot find how). To be clear I'm using android studio, connected to my android phone and that is how I'm using the app on my phone.

Comment: When looking at the permissions of another app on my phone that reads nfc tags, it also says "No permissions allowed".

Comment: Could you show your manifest file?

Comment: NFC is a non dangerous permission so it is not shown in app permission list in settings, it is only defined in the manifest as you have done, may be NFC is not turned on in the user settings or your process is not in the foreground and thus NFC would not be available.

Comment: Compare your manifest with this one (from a official demo of the library you're using). Note that they have a uses-feature rule that may be relevant at the end.  https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-nfc-demo/blob/main/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml